# How to select middle child of an element without :nth pseudo-classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am currently preparing myself for a regional championship in web development for high-school students. Preparation tasks are one the championships website to solve. I have the following HTML code:

```
<h2>Task 6</h2>
  <article id="task-6">
    <div class="marble" data-target></div>
    <section class="first">
      <div class="marble" data-target></div>
      <div class="marble"></div>
      <div class="marble" data-target></div>
    </section>
    <div class="marble"></div>
    <section class="last">
      <div class="marble" data-target></div>
      <div class="marble"></div>
      <div class="marble" data-target></div>
    </section>
    <div class="marble" data-target></div>
  </article>
```

My goal is to select the divs with the `marble` class marked with `data-target`, but under following requirements:

- I am not allowed to use these CSS pseudo-classes or CSS selectors:

  - `:nth-child`
  - `:nth-last-child`
  - `:nth-of-type`
  - `:nth-last-of-type`
  - `[data-target]`
  - nor any use of `+` or `~`
- Only one selector is allowed.

I have tried the following selector, however it only selects the `div`s within the section elements.

```
#task-6 section div:not(:not(:first-child):not(:last-child))
```

Can you please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your tried selector -**

```
#task-6 section div:not(:not(:first-child):not(:last-child))
```

It explicitly says to work on divs inside section element

**Just remove section from it and it should work for every elements**

```
#task-6 div:not(:not(:first-child):not(:last-child))
```